# Реальный размер byte в java heap

Tags: java

Я запутался с тем сколько в действительности занимает переменная типа byte в java heap, в одном источнике написано что 1 байт, в другом что 4 байта как и int, в третьем источнике написано что он может увеличиваться до 8 байт, в четвертом что он хоть и занимает 4 байта, но при этом к примеру массив из 20 элементов типа byte будет весить 20 байт в оперативке. Так сколько в дейстивительности занимает переменная типа byte в java heap?

Comment: А почему именно в хипе? Почему не на стеке, например?

Comment: Зависит от jvm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Размер объекта в куче зависит от множества факторов - реализации JVM, её разрядности, использования компактных указателей, выравнивания объектов и т.д. и т.п.

Самый простой и быстрый способ посмотреть сколько объект Byte занимает в вашем случае - запустить входящую в JDK утилиту [jmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html), найти строку java.lang.Byte и разделить значение в колонке bytes на значение в колонке instances

```
$ jmap -histo <PID>

 num     #instances         #bytes  class name (module)
-------------------------------------------------------
...
121:            21            336  java.lang.Byte (java.base@10.0.1)
...
```

Программный путь чуть сложнее. С ним поможет пакет [java.lang.instrument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html). Для начала нам нужен класс *агента*:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

Компилируем

```
$ javac ObjectSizeFetcher
```

Потом создаём файл MANIFEST.MF и добавляем в него строку

```
Premain-Class: ObjectSizeFetcher
```

А после упаковываем класс и манифест в jar

```
$ jar cfm ObjectSizeFetcherAgent.jar MANIFEST.MF ObjectSizeFetcher.class
```

Класс для теста:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Byte b = new Byte("1");
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(b));
    }
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем c предварительно созданным агентом

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java -javaagent:ObjectSizeFetcherAgent.jar Main
```

Код для примера с агентом взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/1911548).