# Мониторинг памяти в Netty 4

Tags: netty

Я не могу найти класс «ObjectSizeEstimator» в Netty 4. Этот класс был в третьей версии, который позволял следить за тем какой объем памяти использует netty, был ли он удален в Netty 4? Если он был удален, есть ли замена для этого класса в Netty 4?

Comment: На сколько я вижу по документации, он просто возвращал объём занимаемой объектом кучи. Не знаю зачем это может понадобиться в Netty, но написать собственную версию можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827546/204271).

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, дело не только в этом, он не просто возвращал объем занимаемой кучи, но и останавливал работу потоков в случае если объем превышал заданное программистом значение в конструкторе класса "OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor" и снова возобновлял работу когда память освобождалась. По крайней мере это было в 3 версии, возможно я ошибаюсь

Comment: Он не останавливал, он только использовался для измерений самим `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor`. Которого тоже в Netty 4 уже нет. Если нужна подобная функциональность, то придётся наследовать от какой-либо реализации `EventExecutorGroup` и переопределять метод `submit`. Зачем вам это?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, Да прошу прощения я ошибся. Мне это нужно чтобы избегать  исключений типа outofmemoryerror итд, В случае если Netty начнет потреблять слишком много памяти на сервере. Мне кажется это надо как-то контролировать, приостанавливать работу, чистить гарбедж коллектором. Иначе все полетит, я скажу честно я не профессионал, возможно я в чем-то не прав.

Comment: Во-первых, при использовании Netty лучше по максимуму сократить использование кучи, оперировать байтовыми буферами в нативной памяти. Во-вторых, словить OOM можно только в двух случаях - при утечках и когда совокупное использованием памяти всеми подключениями больше, чем есть у сервера. Первое решается аккуратным написание кода, второе не решается в принципе, разве что отказом принимать новые соединения.

Comment: Да и EventExecutorGroup стоит использовать только тогда, когда неизбежен вызов блокирующих операций.